# How to fill gap between skew shpae div and other plan ractangle div

Tags: html, css

Please advice me how to fill gap between my skewd div and other non-skewd div.

This is my CSS:

```
body {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
.div1 { background: yellow;height: 577px;float:left;width:100%;transform: skew(0deg, -10deg) translateY(-120px);overflow:hidden;}
.div1-container {transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);float:left;width:100%}
img{width:100%; display:block;}
.aaa{float:left; width:100%; background:#f2f2f2; padding:50px 0;}
.container{width:500px; margin:0 auto;}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="div1">
<div class="div1-container"> <img src="http://www.gensofts.info/projects/nyc/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/shutterstock_442357276-1.jpg" /> </div>
</div>
<div class="aaa">
<div class="container">
    <p>This is new para.</p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu9ff8mn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
.div1 { background: yellow;height: 577px;float:left;width:100%;transform: skew(0deg, -10deg) translateY(-120px);overflow:hidden;}
.div1-container {transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);float:left;width:100%}
img{width:100%; display:block;}

.aaa{width:100%; background:#f2f2f2; padding:50px 0;}
.container{width:500px; margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div1-container"> <img src="http://www.gensofts.info/projects/nyc/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/shutterstock_442357276-1.jpg" /> </div>
</div>
<div class="aaa">
  <div class="container">
      <p>This is new para.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sadik, but 1 thing i can't understood why are you removed float.

Comment: @AnmolRatanMohla if you aren't convinced or you don't understand the answer don't accept it only because it achieve what you want ... you need to ask for more detail as you have to understand. Having only a working code will never help you as you can always face the same issue ... by the way "only code" answer are low quality answer as the purpose is to explain